# Google Sheets: ArrayFormula: Add Previous Value Err If First Value Is Text

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

The ArrayFormula I'm using is doing a cumulative calc, so col D is cumulative... eg =D1+C2 etc. Works fine when I create the ArrayFormula except for the first calc - since D1 is a header (text), not a number.

I tried an IF(), to check IsNumber(), but no good, same error. Any suggestions on how to correct this error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just fixed it. I had tried to use IFERROR(), but did it incorrectly before, now works when I use:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(D1:D1957+C2:C1958,C2:C1958))
```